# PHP Преобразование строки в массив

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть строка:

> PEKKACard.pngGolemCard.pngFreezeCard.pngBombTowerCard.pngHogRiderCard.pngGiantCard.pngBomberCard.pngElixirCollectorCard.pngplease

Причём называться файлы png могут как угодно, но формат всегда png.
Вместо "please" может быть любой текст.
Как мне преобразовать эту строку в массив, чтобы получилось:

```
$arr = [PEKKACard.png; GolemCard.png; FreezeCard.png; BombTowerCard.png; HogRiderCard.png; GiantCard.png; BomberCard.png; ElixirCollectorCard.png; please]
```

То есть    $arr[0]    должен быть    PEKKACard.png    .
А например $arr[8]    должен быть    please
И кстати картинок в формате pn всегда 8 штук и после них идёт любой текст.
P.S: Если вы знаете как это сделать, укажите код, а не технологию :)
Заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
$str="PEKKACard.pngGolemCard.pngFreezeCard.pngBombTowerCard.pngHogRiderCard.pngGiantCard.pngBomberCard.pngElixirCollectorCard.pngplease";
preg_match("/((?:.*?)\.png)((?1))((?1))((?1))((?1))((?1))((?1))((?1))(.*)/", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(129) "PEKKACard.pngGolemCard.pngFreezeCard.pngBombTowerCard.pngHogRiderCard.pngGiantCard.pngBomberCard.pngElixirCollectorCard.pngplease"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "PEKKACard.png"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "GolemCard.png"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "FreezeCard.png"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "BombTowerCard.png"
  [5]=>
  string(16) "HogRiderCard.png"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "GiantCard.png"
  [7]=>
  string(14) "BomberCard.png"
  [8]=>
  string(23) "ElixirCollectorCard.png"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "please"
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/35cd11e08cecbad1271dcfc45d95c7b112907994

https://regex101.com/r/tV7rM5/1

Answer (score 3):

```
$str="PEKKACard.pngGolemCard.pngFreezeCard.pngBombTowerCard.pngHogRiderCard.pngGiantCard.pngBomberCard.pngElixirCollectorCard.pngplease";
$arr=preg_split("/\.png\K/",$str);
var_dump($arr);
```

`\K` в данном регулярном выражении позволяет не включать .png в совпадение и таким образом не вырезать его из текста, как это обычно делает split.